# vimeo embeds: best practices for facebook sharing?

Tags: vimeo

We're embedding Vimeo iframes on our site, and we want people who "Like" these pages on Facebook to have the video play inline in the Newsfeed.

By default, this doesn't seem to happen.

Do we have to manually populate **og:video** tags? My initial strategy would be to just copy the tags from the public Vimeo video page... but this makes embedding the videos much more difficult.

Are there any best practices here?

Comment: pretty sure there are plug-ins that will handle the og:video tags. Or you could write a function in PHP or something that would do that for you. Otherwise, if you really want to *share* video content and not simply link-wh*re your own domain, a direct link to content is probably preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is continually changing its policies around which videos play inline - and they have specific limitations on brands and promotional videos.  Even with perfect metatags, as indicated by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ , our videos sometimes do not play inline.

Facebook caching is also sometimes a problem, if your first attempt at posting does not have the right metadata.